# Sqlite: updating different row on different table when deleting

Tags: php, pdo, triggers, sqlite, foreign-keys

Im working on a small pos system based on php and sqlite3. The DB contains a table for orders and a table which contains the products related (foreign key) to the orders-table. The orders tables has a row which shows the totalsum, which is calculated via PHP. It is the sum of all added products. Everytime when i add or remove a product i have to update the orders table too.

My question: Is it possible to sync the price-row of the orders-table->price with the sum of prices of the added prorducts in sqlite only, so that orders->price is just a reference to sum( related_products->price )?

Comment: Why can't you just compute the sum on the fly when you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is it possible to sync the price-row of the orders-table->price with the sum of prices of the added prorducts in sqlite only*

Do you mean something like this?

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_item_insert
AFTER INSERT ON order_items
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE orders 
     SET price = price + NEW.qty * NEW.price
   WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_item_delete
AFTER DELETE ON order_items
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE orders 
     SET price = price - OLD.qty * OLD.price
   WHERE order_id = OLD.order_id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_item_update
AFTER UPDATE ON order_items
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE orders 
     SET price = price - OLD.qty * OLD.price + NEW.qty * NEW.price
   WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id;
END;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8bed5/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer and the sqlfiddle link. But this will slowup the system too much.
I need something like following logic  as trigger_function

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_item_insert
AFTER INSERT ON order_items
BEGIN
  UPDATE orders 
     SET price = (SELECT sum(price) FROM order_items WHERE order_id= ---> .last_inserted_order_id <---- )
   WHERE order_id = ---> .last_inserted_order_id <----;
END;
//
```

Is it possible to get and use the last_rowid in a trigger-function?

Comment: Your pseudo code **way** slower than what I suggested in my answer because my code adds and subtracts relative amounts to(from) total and doesn't involve `SELECT` statement with an aggregate function. It's as fast you can possibly get. SQLite supports only row-based triggers, thus the piece of code in the trigger will be executed for each affected row. More over there is no notion of last inserted id per order if it's what you mean. It's a logical application level abstraction. DB has no clue what was the last order_item per order inserted.